# How to order ax.scatter and ax.quiver in Python 3D plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I want to draw a spin systems. I have the picture below. However, I want the quivers to be INSIDE the scatter circles and the "Main arrow" to be a bright one. Thus, how can I order three plots?
Thank You in advance!

[image: picture of the spin systems]

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
############################## A sphere #################################
r = 4
pi = np.pi
cos = np.cos
sin = np.sin
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0.0:pi:100j, 0.0:2.0*pi:100j]
x = r*sin(phi)*cos(theta)
y = r*sin(phi)*sin(theta)
z = r*cos(phi)

#Set colours and render
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=1, cstride=1, color='red', alpha=0.6, linewidth=0)
############################ One arrow ########################
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
z1 = 0 
dx1 = 0
dy1 = 0
dz1 = 2
ax.quiver(x1, y1, z1, dx1, dy1, dz1, pivot='middle', color="blue", linewidths=5.0,length=1.4)
ax.scatter(0, 0, 0,color="blue", s=800)
############################ Array of arrows ############################################
ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
ax.set_ylim([-4,4])
ax.set_zlim([-4,4])
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.tight_layout()

N = 5 # number of points - 5x5x5
scale = 0.4 # scale for the increment of an arrow

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

xx = np.linspace(-3.5, 3.5, N)
yy = np.linspace(-3.5, 3.5, N)
zz = np.linspace(-3.5, 3.5, N)

dxx = scale*np.random.rand(N)
dyy = scale*np.random.rand(N)
dzz = scale*np.random.rand(N)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(yy, zz, xx)
dx, dy, dz = np.meshgrid(dxx, dyy, dzz)
ax.scatter(x, y, z,color="orange", s=200)
ax.quiver(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, pivot='middle', length=1.6, color="blue")
plt.show()
```